# Брать строки файла и поочерёдно закидывать их в переменные - возможно на js?

Tags: php, javascript

Мне надо чтоб я закинул в файл например, 10 строк, каждую из которых мне надо закидывать в отдельную переменную(получается 10 переменных). В интернете ничего не нашел. Впринципе, можно и на php сделать, нашел такой код:
`

```
<?php
$handle = fopen("/tmp/inputfile.txt", "r");
while (!feof($handle)) {
    $buffer = fgets($handle, 4096);
    echo $buffer;
}
fclose($handle);
?>
```

`
Однако, как мне работать с переменными php в js?? Подскажите пожалуйста!

Comment: Опишите, пожалуйста, вашу конечную цель. Возможно, вы ставите не правильный вопрос

Answer (score 0):

нужен jQuery (или любая другая библиотека с ajax)

```
PHP:
    <?php
      $gg=file("gg.txt",FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);//чтение файла в массив(построчно)
      echo json_encode($gg);//вывести массив в json формате
    ?>
JS:
    var data;
    $.ajax({
      url:"test.php",
      async:false,
      cache:false,
      success:function(dat){
        data=JSON.parse(dat);//делаем из строки нормальный js массив
      }
    });
```

Comment: Не понял что делать Ваш код. Можете пожалуйста объяснить?

Comment: Посмотрите правки

Comment: Это я понял, однако как мне теперь каждый элемент массива со строками брать?

Comment: data[index].... Это просто массив